# Tree with tikz looks the way it's meant to look but still errors are popping up

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-trees

I just started learning LaTeX and to do so I tried to create a PDF of my last logic assignment. Therefore I had to create a resolution tree. After Googling I found some examples for using tikz-trees on this platform.
My result is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,trees}

\begin{document}
        \begin{landscape}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          grow'=up,
          level 1/.style={sibling distance=16em},
          level 2/.style={sibling distance=15em},
          level 3/.style={sibling distance=15em},
          level 4/.style={sibling distance=12em}]
        \node (f) {$\Box$} 
        child { node (1l) {
            \begin{tabular}
            $\varphi_{T32}$ \\
            $Q(a, f(g(a)))$ \\
            \end{tabular}}
          child { node (2ll) {
            \begin{tabular}
            $\varphi_{T31}$ \\
            $Q(a, f(g(a))) \lor R(g(a), f(g(a)))$
            \end{tabular}}
                child {node (3lll) {
                    \begin{tabular}
                    $(\varphi_2)_{[x/a \text{, } y/f(g(a))]}$ \\
                    $Q(a, f(g(a))) \lor R(g(a), f(g(a))) \lor \lnot P(g(a))$ \\
                    \end{tabular}}}
                child {node (3llr) {
                    \begin{tabular}
                    $\varphi_{T1}$ \\
                    $P(g(a))$
                    \end{tabular}}
                    child { node(llrl) {
                        \begin{tabular}
                        $(\varphi_3)_{[x/f(a) \text{, } y/b]}$ \\
                        $Q(f(a),g(b)) \lor P(g(a))$ \\
                        \end{tabular}}}
                    child { node(llrr) {
                        \begin{tabular}
                        $\varphi_4$ \\
                        $\lnot Q(f(a),g(b)) \\
                        \end{tabular}}}}}
          child { node (2lr) {
            \begin{tabular}
            $\varphi_{T2}$ \\
            \lnot R(g(a), f(g(a))) \\
            \end{tabular}}
            child {node (3lrl) {
                \begin{tabular}
                $\varphi_{T1}$ \\
                $P(g(a))$
                \end{tabular}}}
            child {node (3lrr) {
                \begin{tabular}
                $\varphi_1_{[x/g(a)]}$ \\
                $\lnot R(g(a), f(g(a)) \lor \lnot P(g(a)))$ \\
                \end{tabular}}}}
        }
        child {node (1r) {\begin{tabular}
            $(\varphi_5)_{[y/a]}$ \\
            $\lnot Q(a, f(g(a)))$ \\
        \end{tabular}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

And this looks exactly the way I wanted it to look like, but nevertheless there are still some errors popping up and for learning reasons I wanted to ask you guys what my mistakes are, because this time it works but maybe I will make the same mistake next time and it does not compile anymore.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.  And the errors may depend on the packages that are used.  Also, please edit the question and include the error messages that you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix the problems.

What have I done?

- added missing `$` signs where required (I added 3 of these in total);
- avoided 'double subscripts' e.g. if you say `$x_i_1$` you will get an error - you need to group things: `$x_{i_1}$`, for example;
- removed the `tabular` environments which aren't needed if you add `align=center` for the picture, and removed final line breaks (just for neatness);
- I removed `inputenc` just because I'm not using that encoding in my editor (but I strongly advise considering using `utf8`);
- I replaced `amsmath` with `mathtools` - this loads `amsmath` plus a few fixes/enhancements.

If you *read the errors* when you compile, many of them tell you what the problem is. Not always but definitely in the case of the missing `$` signs, for example.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,trees}

\begin{document}
        \begin{landscape}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          align=center,
          grow'=up,
          level 1/.style={sibling distance=16em},
          level 2/.style={sibling distance=15em},
          level 3/.style={sibling distance=15em},
          level 4/.style={sibling distance=12em}]
        \node (f) {$\Box$}
        child { node (1l) {
            $\varphi_{T32}$ \\
            $Q(a, f(g(a)))$
          }
          child { node (2ll) {
            $\varphi_{T31}$ \\
            $Q(a, f(g(a))) \lor R(g(a), f(g(a)))$
            }
                child {node (3lll) {
                     $(\varphi_2)_{[x/a \text{, } y/f(g(a))]}$ \\
                    $Q(a, f(g(a))) \lor R(g(a), f(g(a))) \lor \lnot P(g(a))$
                    }}
                child {node (3llr) {
                    $\varphi_{T1}$ \\
                    $P(g(a))$
                    }
                    child { node(llrl) {
                        $(\varphi_3)_{[x/f(a) \text{, } y/b]}$ \\
                        $Q(f(a),g(b)) \lor P(g(a))$
                        }}
                    child { node(llrr) {
                        $\varphi_4$ \\
                        $\lnot Q(f(a),g(b))$
                        }}}}
          child { node (2lr) {
            $\varphi_{T2}$ \\
            $\lnot R(g(a), f(g(a)))$
            }
            child {node (3lrl) {
                $\varphi_{T1}$ \\
                $P(g(a))$
                }}
            child {node (3lrr) {
                $\varphi_{1_{[x/g(a)]}}$ \\
                $\lnot R(g(a), f(g(a)) \lor \lnot P(g(a)))$
                }}}
        }
        child {node (1r) {
            $(\varphi_5)_{[y/a]}$ \\
            $\lnot Q(a, f(g(a)))$
        }}
    ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: fixed tree]